# Get 8*8 blocks of an image to an arrayList

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, emgucv, bmp

This is my code to take an ArrayList of 8*8 blocks of an image (Bmp) and it's not working. What is the flaw of the logic here? 'rows' is the number of rows of the image. I am doing my video steganography project.

```
        int x = 0;
        int colCount = 0;

        int yStart = 0;
        int yLimit = 8;

        for (x = 0;x < rows; x++)
        {
            while (yStart<yLimit)
            {
                imageBlock[x % 8, yStart % 8] = image_array[0].Data[x, yStart, 1];

                if (x % 8 == 7 && yStart % 8 == 7)
                {
                    blockList.Add(ForwardDCT(imageBlock));
                }

                yStart++;
            }

            if (x == rows - 1)
            { 
                x = 0;
                yLimit = yLimit + 8;
                //yStart = yStart + 8;
                colCount++;

                if (colCount == 100)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (yStart % 8 == 7)
            {
                yStart = yLimit - 8;
            }
        }
```

Comment: " and it's not working" - please provide more accurate details...

Comment: Sorry, it dosn't add any block to the arrayList. Count of the List is alwasys 0. @MitchWheat

Comment: Next time please, delete the unneccesy new lines. Do you use breakpointsat blocklist.Add(something)? It was triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw in the logic is that you've got a single `imageBlock`, and you overwrite the data in it several times before calling `ForwardDCT(imageBlock)`.

You should change your loop structure to go in grid steps 8x8, then have two more loops that copy the content of the grid into `imageBlock`, and call `ForwardDCT(imageBlock)` on it rigth away:

```
for (var blockRow = 0 ; blockRow < rows ; blockRow += 8) {
    for (var blockCol = 0 ; blockCol < yLimit ; blockCol += 8) {
        for (var r = 0 ; r != 8 ; r++) {
            for (var c = 0 ; c != 8 ; c++) {
                // Add a check to see that blockRow+r, blockCol+c
                // are inside the original image
                imageBlock[r][c] = image_array[0].Data[blockRow+r, blockCol+c, 1];
            }
        }
        blockList.Add(ForwardDCT(imageBlock));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail? I would be grateful if you can provide me a code snippet.

Comment: It did the trick. Thank you sir!